# Laravel transaction

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In regarding of Transaction, I have seen two way of doing this and what is the difference of them two and the benefit?

These code in the repo.

Example 1 common approach

```
DB::transaction(function () {

});
```

What the purpose of this example?

```
public function createCustomer(Request $request, $id)
    {   
        $self = $this;

        return $this->model->getConnection()->transaction(function () use ($self, $request, $id) {

        });
}
```

Comment: The only difference is the way in which the PDO connection is accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually when you'll use the following code:

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    // ...
});
```

Laravel will will use the default connection provided in the `config/.env` file but if you want to use a different connection for the model then you may use the following code, for example:

```
return $this->model->getConnection()->transaction(...);
```

In this case your model should contain a protected property to use as it's connection, for example:

```
class SomeModel extends Model {

    protected $connection = 'pgsql';
}
```

That's it.